# Changing existing components/applications?

Tags: ofbiz

Can I change existing applications for example accounting. Like removing fields and menus not required, by not breaking the application? Or, is it possible to make a copy of the application/component and change it without changing the original?

Answer (score 2):

The Question is already answered in the Developer FAQ, Tips and Tricks.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=82706476#FAQTipsTricksCookbookHowTo-BestPracticeModifyOrCreate